# Using angular.dart with Bootstrap yields Object #<Document> has no method 'getAttribute'

Tags: dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

When using Angular.dart 0.9.10 with bootstrap 3.1.1, and compiling to Javascript, I get an ugly stacktrace attached below.

The stacktrace is printed in the console any time I for instance focus a textfield or enter some text.

This has worked previously, so I wonder if it is a bug with the shadow_dom implementation?

The app is currently quite simple and works correctly with Dartium. The same issue occurs after javascript compilation in both Firefox and Chrome.

It works when I remove below line from index.html

```
<script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
```

[image: Stacktrace]
The stacktrace in pure text:

```
TypeError {stack: "TypeError: Object # has no method 'getAt…/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2805:28)", message: "Object # has no method 'getAttribute'"}
message: "Object # has no method 'getAttribute'"
stack: "TypeError: Object # has no method 'getAttribute'↵    at Function.Sizzle.attr (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:1422:9)↵    at Array. (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:1618:25)↵    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2116:22↵    at superMatcher (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2322:12)↵    at select (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2483:28)↵    at Function.Sizzle (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:838:9)↵    at HTMLDocument.jQuery.event.handlers (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4416:48)↵    at HTMLDocument.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4353:40)↵    at Document.elemData.handle (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4057:28)↵    at invoke (http://localhost:8000/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2805:28)"
__proto__: Error
constructor: function TypeError() { [native code] }
name: "TypeError"
stack: undefined
__proto__: d
 "TypeError: Object # has no method 'getAttribute'
    at Function.Sizzle.attr (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:1422:9)
    at Array. (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:1618:25)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2116:22
    at superMatcher (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2322:12)
    at select (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2483:28)
    at Function.Sizzle (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:838:9)
    at HTMLDocument.jQuery.event.handlers (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4416:48)
    at HTMLDocument.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4353:40)
    at Document.elemData.handle (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4057:28)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8000/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2805:28)"
```

Comment: It seems the shadow_dom polyfill conflicts with jQuery. Maybe your shadow_dom package got updated with the angular update? Which version of the shadow_dom package are you using?

Comment: Looking at pubspec.lock says I am using 0.9.2 of shadow dom. (And 2.1.0 of JQuery)

Comment: Angular 0.9.9 used the same version as far as I know. I don't expect a different result but can you try 'shadow_dom.min.js' instead of 'shadow_dom.debug.js' anyway?

Comment: Yes it is the same with the minified file: `{stack: "TypeError: Object #<b> has no method 'getAttribute…00/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js:1:27285)", message: "Object #<b> has no method 'getAttribute'"}
 "TypeError: Object #<b> has no method 'getAttribute'`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure on the exact details why, but angular dart has a boostrap implementation:
https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui

Likely, that one will work better for you.

Best Regards,
Paul

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.